# Como identificar queries que não usam indexes?

Tags: mysql

Depois de muito tempo resolvi verificar o estado do banco de dados, mesmo com tudo funcionando normal. Usei o [`mysqltuner.pl`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl/master/mysqltuner.pl) para verificar.

---

Num dos pontos existe a seguinte informação:

```
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 8915215
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 0% (6K on disk / 19B total)
```

---

**A minha questão é:**

Como posso identificar, de forma rápida, quais são esses JOINS que não estão usando indexes?

Comment: Já usou [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html)

Comment: @Maniero O problema é descobrir em qual usar. São muitas queries diferentes (com `JOIN`  diferentes), não faço a minima ideia da origem desses 8915215. Usando o EXPLAIN teria que executar em cada uma individualmente em cada query, ou há uma forma de usar um EXPLAIN num "histórico" de queries que já foram usadas? . Eu vi sobre o `slow_query_log`, mas as informações que encontro são conflitantes (ele não necessariamente registra aquilo que não usa indexes).

Comment: Bem, talvez isso me deu uma ideia. Pensei em ter que adicionar o EXPLAIN manualmente em cada uma. Mas, pensar melhor, dá para modificar o código fonte lá do [`database/sql`](https://golang.org/src/database/sql/sql.go?s=73205:73261#L2583) e então faço executar duas queries, uma normal (para o código não parar) e outra com o `EXPLAIN` (alá EXPLAIN + query) e essa segunda da um print e executo todos os testes. Gambiarras das gambiarras, não custa tentar, mas deve ter uma solução melhor.